# Viability of reduction of oil paint binder and solvent flammability upon disposal via addition of water

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

As an artist, when disposing of a paper towel or rag with oil paint, turpentine, odorless turpentine substitute or mineral spirits at the end of a painting session, I generally pour water over the paper towel or rag to reduce its flammability. Sometimes I rinse out the paper towel or rag in the sink before disposal to reduce concentration of the solvent. Does mixing water with the oil paint binder and solvent actually reduce its flammability? I understand mixtures can be categorized as suspension, colloidal or solution, and I would be curious to know whether or how this categorization pertains.

Comment: Better suited to: tps://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay thanks; I'll check there.